# Canon pixma ip 4850 driver problem on 14.04 64

Tags: drivers, printing, dependencies, canon

when installing driver I get dependences problems `libtiff4` missing.

Drivers downloaded from Canon:

- ip4800_redhat_debian_guide.tar,
- including cnijfilter-common_3.40-1_amd64.deb
- and cnijfilterip4800series_3.40-1_amd64.deb

Those worked fine on earlier Ubuntu, last installed on 13.10 used `gdebi`.

Comment: what driver?  where did you download it from? how are you trying to install it?  Please add these details to your question.  Thanks.

Comment: Quote: Please add these details to your question. Thanks. - [See your original question - That was the idea!] To improve some more you can add the actual links as well.

Comment: get 404 not found, looked in synaptic, cant find those files

Comment: Tried again, copied from the german site, worked, installed and working, Thank You fore the help

Comment: This solution also works for Canon MG5450 LAN!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the ip 4850 work on Ubuntu 14.04, you will need to install the following library:

```
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tiff3/libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_a‌​md64.deb
```

(64 bit)

or

```
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tiff3/libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_i386.deb
```

(32 bit)